# how to make sure that sap.m.select is filled with data

Tags: sapui5

I have a sap.m.select that is loaded with data in the beggining of the app.
I can only proceed forward if the select control contains data.
I want to make sure that the data is loaded and then enable a button "Go".

I checked that a list control has "attachUpdateFinished". Do we have something similar for select.
or is there any other way i can do it?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you elaborate on how the sap.m.select is load with data? Is it binded to a model?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `sap.m.Select` control is bound to a model?

In that case, you can enable the button in your model's `attachRequestCompleted` event handler:

```js
oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function (oEvent) {
    oYourGoButton.setEnabled(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Button `enabled` property to the same model as `sap.m.Select`and create a custom formatter as following in your controller:

```
enableFormatter:function(items){
    if(items&&items.length>0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Please run and check the code snippet.

```html
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons" data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"></script>
<!-- define an XMLView - normally done in a separate file -->
<script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.commons.layout" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="my.own.controller" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <Select items="{/items}">
            <core:Item key="{name}" text="{value}" />
        </Select>
        <Button text="Go" enabled="{path:'/items',formatter:'.enableFormatter'}" />

        <Select items="{/itemsempty}">
            <core:Item key="{name}" text="{value}" />
        </Select>
        <Button text="Go" enabled="{path:'/itemsempty',formatter:'.enableFormatter'}" />

    </mvc:View>
</script>


<script>
    sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {

        onInit: function() {
            var data = {
                items: [{
                    name: 1,
                    value: 1
                }, {
                    name: 2,
                    value: 2
                }],
                itemsempty: []
            };
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            oModel.setData(data);
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
        },

        enableFormatter: function(items) {
            if (items && items.length > 0) return true;
            return false;
        }


    });


    var myView = sap.ui.xmlview("myView", {
        viewContent: jQuery('#view1').html()
    }); // 
    myView.placeAt('content');
</script>

</head>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
    <div id='content'></div>
</body>
```